# Android print image using BIXOLON SPP-R300

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-2.3-gingerbread, bixolon-printer

I'm developing application which prints image using Bixolon SPP-R300 mobile printer via Bluetooth.My problem is I can't print my image on whole width of paper. Printer decreases dimensions very much, but saved pictures dimensions in Android is well.I want to print image on whole width.I looked in users manual of Bixolon for android but didn't help. Also in internet there is no information about it.So, I don't know what to do. Here is a code snippet from my project which prints image:

```
mBxlService = new BxlService(); 
mBxlService.Connect();
if (mBxlService.GetStatus() == BxlService.BXL_SUCCESS) {
    returnValue = mBxlService.PrintImage(mypath.getPath(), 
                                         384, 
                                         BxlService.BXL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER, 
                                         40);
    if (returnValue == BxlService.BXL_SUCCESS) {
        returnValue = mBxlService.LineFeed(2);                          
    } 
}
```

In user manual,where is written that "Set to a value of 384, image is fit to full size of paper" didn't helped.
Here is a printed image.

[image: also I attached,printed image]
and here is manual
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The printer you are using has 576 dots per line.  The SPP200 has 384 dots.