# Android Java Bixolon SPP-R300 Print Image and Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bixolon-printer

I'm developing application which prints using Bixolon SPP-R300 mobile printer via Bluetooth.
I've managed to make the Bluetooth connection, print Text and do `lineFeed` but i still don't know how to print images.
For the text i have this working:

```
returnValue = mBxlService.PrintText("Text Example",
                BxlService.BXL_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
                BxlService.BXL_FT_DEFAULT,
                BxlService.BXL_TS_0WIDTH | BxlService.BXL_TS_0HEIGHT);
```

The `mBxlService` have a method for image too (`mBxlService.PrintImage`).

I want to print a image from the `drawable` folder in the project. Something like `drawable/image.png`

Someone have worked with this printer or know how to print images with it? There is few information about this, and i'm really trying here.

Other thing is, every time i connect the printer to android a pairing request happens, there is something to bypass that? to do that by code?

This is the printer: [Bixolon SPP-R300](http://bixolon.com/html/en/product/product_detail.xhtml?pgNum=1&prod_id=19&large_cd=0003&small_cd=0000)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my language, English is not my main language.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link (it has a snipped of code to print image)
[Android print image using BIXOLON SPP-R300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976740/android-print-image-using-bixolon-spp-r300)

And here is the how you can get URI to your resource:
[how to get an uri of an image resource in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android)

So, overall code will look something like this:

```
Uri picturePath = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.image_1);

mBxlService = new BxlService(); 
mBxlService.Connect();
if (mBxlService.GetStatus() == BxlService.BXL_SUCCESS) {
    returnValue = mBxlService.PrintImage(picturePath.toString(), 
                                         384, 
                                         BxlService.BXL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER, 
                                         40);
    if (returnValue == BxlService.BXL_SUCCESS) {
        returnValue = mBxlService.LineFeed(2);                          
    } 
}
```

Sure, you need to replace "your.package.name" and R.drawable.image_1.

Also, there is a chance that it won't like a path to resources. In such case, I would recommend to spit the image out to SD card and print it from there.